# Accessing intranet websites and servers through oracle VM

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have a bunch of server's running on my company's intranet. I am able to access the intranet websites and the server through my laptop.

Problem is that I am not able to do the same using the windows 7 OS running in oracle VM Box installed in my laptop.

I have tried changing the network adapter settings to NAT, Bridged etc, but no improvement.

I am pretty sure that someone would have faced this problem but I was not able to find this issue reported anywhere even though I've been browsing from last night.

Any suggestions..?

Answer (score 1):

so first thing you need to do is divide and conquer your problem, you have either a DNS problem, or you have a route problem, or you have a "something the admin has done is keeping me from getting to the machines problem"...

go to a machine that can get to the intranet. type into the cmd `ping someIntranetLocation`, that should give you an IP address.

go to vmbox and type the same thing: `ping someIntranetLocation` if it gives you the same thing then you have ruled out DNS problems...

if you have DNS problems, copy the DNS server settings from a working machine to the VMBox machine, see if that fixes it.

if you do not have DNS problems, then you should check your address and subnet mask to see if you are on a different subnet... so if your address is `10.10.10.1` and the subnet mask is `255.255.255.0`, that means that you need to match the dest IP with all but the last octet to be on the same `subnet`, so the `10.10.10.x` needs to be the same, if they aren't on the same subnet then your connection needs to be routed and that is the responsibility of your gateway, what your gateway is, I don't know, it could be the host or the hosts gateway depending on how the VM is set up...

if you go through all of that and still can connect, then you need to investigate something more pro-active keeping you from your goal, like MAC address filtering, or authenticated firewalls, or some fancy VPN keeping you out...

Comment: Of course I am having DNS issues, but copying the DNS setting from the host to the oracle VM guest is not helping.. I am able to access all the intranet sites and servers thorugh my VM when I am within my company network but the same is not possible from my house.

Comment: @HorribleGuy, when you are home you can access them through a VPN? and the host VPN connection isn't shared, is that correct?

Comment: I don't configure any VPN manually, I use one of the well known CITRIX Receiver. If only I can use the host network accesses within my VM

Comment: @HorribleGuy have you tried setting up an SSH tunnel between the host and the VM? That would probably let you use the host  vpn from your guest VM.